# Pandas.plotting doesn't show graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, machine-learning

I'm following the tutorial in the book "introduction to machine learning with python" and i've copied the following code:

```
#create dataframe from data in X_train
#label the colums using the strings in iris_dataset.features_names
iris_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(X_train, columns = iris_dataset.feature_names)
#create a scatter matrix from the dataframe, color by y_train
pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(iris_dataframe,c=y_train,
                           figsize=(15,15), marker='o', 
                           hist_kwds={'bins':20},s=60, 
                           alpha=.8,
                           cmap=mglearn.cm3)
```

It should plot a graph,but it only print those lines:

```
array([[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f0d073934a8>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f0d07352908>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f0d07376e48>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f0d0732ee48>],
       [<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f0d072e3f28>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f0d072e3f60>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f0d07308ac8>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f0d07211400>],
       [<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f0d071ca470>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f0d07183470>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f0d071be470>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f0d07165e80>],
       [<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f0d07127390>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f0d070e5390>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f0d0709d390>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f0d07047da0>]], dtype=object)
```

Can someone tell me a reason?

EDIT-SOLVED:I do not know why but a after a re-run of the cells, the graph apperead..

Comment: Maybe look through the Pandas documentation for plotting and see if your missing something? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html

Comment: I think all those examples in docs expect to be ran in something like Jupyter, which automatically shows the graphs. If you're running this in a regular python interpreter, you'll need to call `matplotlib.pyplot.show` yourself.

Comment: Sometimes in Jupyter you have to turn on inline plots, `%matplotlib inline`

Comment: if you solved it yourself, then post an answer to your own question instead of editing the original

Comment: You can suppress the lines of text output, which are the str() or repr() (I forget which) version of the value returned by the scatter
_matrix() function. 

To do so, just set the output to a variable:


`axes = pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(iris_dataframe,c=y_train, ...`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

pandas does not have a plotting library in itself. most users normally utilize the matplotlib library when plotting which has a different set of commands. Assuming you have all of the correct libraries installed including matplotlib I would end your code with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#assuming you got the correct conversion to a pandas dataframe  
pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(df,c=y_train,
                       figsize=(15,15), marker='o', 
                       hist_kwds={'bins':20},s=60, 
                       alpha=.8,
                       cmap=mglearn.cm3)


plt.show()
```

Here is a [link](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html#matplotlib.pyplot.showhttps://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html#matplotlib.pyplot.show) to the matplotlib library that goes into the plt.show() There is also methods to save the figure, which can be found in the documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!
I do not know why but after a re-run of all the cells of the jupyter notebook, the graph apperead correctly.

Comment: you have to ensure that you use the statement "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt" in your cell for this to work. if you are calling a function that will plot the graph, then ensure that you use the statement inside the function's definition